# Angular 4 : Conditional display on user status

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

here is the problem :

I try to follow this small tutorial in order to make some conditional display in my current app, depending on user loggedIn status. Here is the link :

https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-hide-navbar-login-page/

It looks pretty simple & efficient. But, I can't get it working within my current application. Following the main tutorial guidelines, I come to this code :

*top-menu.component.ts :*

```
authStatus: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private authService: AuthService){
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.authStatus = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
}

login(){
    this.authService.login();
}

logout(){
    this.authService.logout();
}
```

*top-menu.component.html :*

```
<li><span (click)="login()">LOGIN</span></li>
<li><span (click)="logout()">LOGOUT</span></li>
//...
<li *ngIf="authStatus | async"><a [routerLink]="['/login']">CONDITIONAL LOGIN</a></li>
<li *ngIf="!authStatus | async"><a [routerLink]="['/logout']">CONDITIONAL LOGOUT</a></li>
```

*auth.service.ts :*

```
public loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

get isLoggedIn(){
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
}

login(){
    this.loggedIn.next(true);
}

logout(){
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
}
```

Can anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong...? I checked some other examples on the internet but with no success...

Thanks for reading/help

Comment: why you assign 2 time this.authStatus in contructor, oninit, what is the purpose

Comment: guess I'm wrong with the "subscription part", that was not part of the tutorial, your comment is right, i delete this line. But this does not solve the problem....

Comment: don't remove subscription from constructor..remove from `ngOnInit`

Comment: @Rahul Why? How can I then trace the user status in my top-menu component? The purpose is to get the "conditional login/logout" appear/disappear depending on the boolean "authStatus". If I don't subscribe, anyhow, to the service loggedIn status, that shall not work... Am I wrong?

Comment: keep `this.subscription = this.authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(result => { 
        this.authStatus = result; 
    });` in constructor.

Comment: @Julo0sS Please see below answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
login(){
    this.authStatus = this.authService.login();
}

logout(){
   this.authStatus =  this.authService.logout();
}
```

remove from constructor, onint code

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Here is link of [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LMUDDHynMkoAp7DdAHro?p=preview)

```
authStatus: boolean;
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private authService: AuthService){
     this.subscription = this.authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(result => { 
        this.authStatus = result; 
     });
}

ngOnInit(){
   // this.authStatus = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
}

login(){
    this.authService.login();
}

logout(){
    this.authService.logout();
}
```

when you click on logout/login respective status will get updated in `this.authStatus` and can easly bind to HTML

`isLoggedIn` function returns you the observable that can be subscribed in constructor. No need to add `this.authStatus = this.authService.isLoggedIn();` in ngOnInit because then this.authStatus would become instance of Observable rather than boolean value which we require.

Comment: top-menu.component.ts, @ subscription line, I get this error : Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Observable<boolean>' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: have you imported `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';` ?

Comment: Same error... Sure I did import subscription. My code above is a simplified sample. My service function signature is this : login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean>

Comment: can you try changing `Observable<boolean>` to `void` ?

Comment: because i guess login function doesn't return anything.

Comment: In my case it returns something, login & logout return function status (worked, failed), some components subscribe to this.. Can not change it to void

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155997/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-rahul).

Comment: then just try to change it as `any` just to see if subscription working or not ?

Comment: here https://plnkr.co/edit/LMUDDHynMkoAp7DdAHro?p=preview link of plunkr

Comment: @Julo0sS did you got a chance to look at plunkr ? I am eager to know if its working or not